# Compatibility Issues with Hibernate 6.3.1Final Upgrade: Seeking a Unified GenerationType for MySQL and Postgres Databases

Tags: mysql, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

**Description:**

After upgrading to Hibernate 6.3.1Final, the use of @GeneratedValue(strategy="GenerationType.AUTO") has encountered issues.

In MySQL and Postgres databases, it now expects <entity_name>_seq, which is not practical for our scenario.
To maintain backward compatibility, we have added properties, and while this works in Postgres (as hibernate_sequence already exists), it fails in MySQL.

We are hesitant to create the hibernate_sequence table in MySQL.
As a workaround, GenerationType.IDENTITY works in MySQL, but we are in search of a common solution that functions seamlessly in both databases, given that the entity used is the same.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table")
public class Table{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) // Issue with this line after Hibernate upgrade
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    // Other entity fields and methods

}
```

**Additional Context:**

- Hibernate version: 6.3.1Final
- Database: MySQL and Postgres Desired
- Outcome: Seeking a common GenerationType that works uniformly across
  both databases without the need for additional table creation.

**Attempts Made:**

- Using GenerationType.IDENTITY works in MySQL but is not a universal solution because in Postgres it clashes and generates an already existing Id.
- Backward compatibility properties added, working in Postgres but not in MySQL as it expects hibernate_sequence which isn't feasible practically.

**Question:**

Is there a way to configure Hibernate 6.3.1Final to use a common GenerationType for MySQL and Postgres without the need for additional database-specific configurations or table creations?

**Tried below approaches:**

1. Using GenerationType.IDENTITY works in MySQL but is not a universal solution because in Postgres it clashes and generates an already existing Id.
2. Backward compatibility properties added, working in Postgres but not in MySQL as it expects hibernate_sequence which isn't feasible practically.

Comment: what about declaring a `@SequenceGenerator` and use it, have you tried this approach yet ?

Comment: We thought of this approach, but we have a database with multiple tables, each representing a distinct entity, and they already contain data. So carrying this out for all the entities will be like lot of overheads. Is there any automated approach to create sequences in MySQL and PostgreSQL considering I need to initialize these sequences from the last used value in each table. How can I achieve this efficiently?

Comment: facing the same issues currently, may i ask you to add the backwards compatibility stuff you tried for PG? thx!

Comment: You could set sequence name as param in annotation, have you tried it ? It should start from current value that sequence have

Comment: @FranzEbner Backward compatibility property is spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.db_structure_naming_strategy: legacy